# Introduced a new layer using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

I would like to introduce a new layer as activation function in tensorflow. However, There are errors that can not be solved.
This is code of new layer.

```
def smooth_relu(tensor):
    e=0.15
    alpha=0.005

    def smooth(tensor):

            smoothtensor=tf.cond(tensor<(e+alpha) ,lambda: (tensor-alpha)*(tensor-alpha),lambda:e*((tensor-alpha)-self.e*0.5),    tf.cond(
                        pred,
                        true_fn=None,
                        false_fn=None,
                        strict=False,
                        name=None,
                        fn1=None,
                        fn2=None
                        ))


            return (smoothtensor)



    newtensor=tf.cond(tensor<0 ,lambda :0, lambda:smooth(tensor))
    # In addition to return the result, we return my_random for initializing on each
    # iteration and alpha to check the final value used.

    return (newtensor)
```

This is error.

```
ValueError: Shape must be rank 0 but is rank 2 for 'cond/Switch' (op: 'Switch') with input shapes: [1,1], [1,1].
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because there is no attributes to assign for `smoothtensor` as `dtype`

your fault is in this line :

```
def smooth(tensor): `smoothtensor=tf.cond(tensor<(e+alpha) ,lambda: (tensor-alpha)*(tensor-alpha),lambda:e*((tensor-alpha)-self.e*0.5),dtype=tf.float32)`
```

the available attributes that you can assign :

```
tf.cond(
    pred,
    true_fn=None,
    false_fn=None,
    strict=False,
    name=None,
    fn1=None,
    fn2=None
)
```

EDIT:

Just add a paranthesis in the end of the line code...it is missing

Comment: Thanks.I modified code.However,A new error has appeared. I do not understand the input of tensorflow.